# iframe in console application

Tags: iframe, c1-cms

I have made a console application in Composite C1. This console application shows a list of dataitems. When you edit a dataitem it will show a tab with the information from the dataitem. On another tab I want to show a pdf that is referenced from the dataitem.

I would like to do it in the style of the 'Preview' tab when you edit a page.

So just an iFrame to show the pdf file.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to achieve this?
Is it possible to create a preview like tab.

thanks in advance,
Goldhorn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The auto generated data item editor view currently do not have support for preview.

You would need to either move the preview to a 'view' command you show in the tree or create a custom page to create the edit form/preview functionality.

Here is a sample Tree Definition file which shows how a new command is attached to an existing data element in the trees:

```
<ElementStructure xmlns="http://www.composite.net/ns/management/trees/treemarkup/1.0" xmlns:f="http://www.composite.net/ns/function/1.0"> 
  <ElementStructure.AutoAttachments> 
    <DataType Type="Composite.Data.Types.IPage" Position="Top" /> 
  </ElementStructure.AutoAttachments> 
  <ElementRoot> 
    <Actions> 
      <CustomUrlAction Label="View" Url="~/MyView.aspx?Id=${C1:Data:Composite.Data.Types.IPage:Id}" /> 
    </Actions> 
  </ElementRoot> 
</ElementStructure>
```

To make this hook on to your data type replace the two occurrences of "Composite.Data.Types.IPage" with your types full name (type namespace + name).

Tree definitions are stored as xml files in the folder ~/App_Data/Composite/TreeDefinitions - once you put the file there Composite C1 will pick it up, and in this case attach a command to some types of tree elements.

Read more about [Tree Definitions](http://docs.composite.net/Console/Guide-to-Applications).

If you are going for the custom edit form with preview in it you would also use a Tree Definition to 'hook in' your custom form.

The custom page you invoke inside the C1 Console need to abide to some rules - grab a copy of ~/Composite/content/views/log/log.aspx and gut it and you have a starting point for your custom page.